# Black background color on SwiftUI list item when reordering

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am trying to implement list reordering, basic code example:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    @State var items = [
        "One",
        "Two",
        "Three"
    ]

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            ZStack {
                Color.gray
                    .ignoresSafeArea()

                List($items, id: \.self, editActions: .move) { $item in
                    ListItem(text: item)
                }
                .scrollContentBackground(.hidden)
                .listStyle(.plain)
            }
            .navigationTitle("Test")
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
        }
    }

}

struct ListItem: View {

    let text: String

    var body: some View {
        Text(text)
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .padding()
            .background(.blue)
            .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 4.0))
            .listRowSeparator(.hidden)
            .listRowBackground(Color.clear)
    }

}



struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

It all works fine and well however when I long press to begin the drag gesture the background for the list item appears black. I have added all the modifiers such as `listRowBackground` and `scrollContentBackground` but the problem persists. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use your page background color (gray) for your `listRowBackground` modifier.

```
    Text(text)
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        .foregroundColor(.white)
        .padding()
        .background(.blue)
        .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 4.0))
        .listRowSeparator(.hidden)
        .listRowBackground(Color.gray)
```

[image]

Comment: This still shows a background color when the list item is dragged, you can see the gray background with the padding around it

Comment: That's right. Maybe in the internal animation of `List` the highlighted cell is a GraphicsContext copy of the underlying cell, and that one doesn't know translucency. Maybe.

Comment: Yeah usual SwiftUI woes "wow this is so cool, oh actually I can't use it unless it's used exactly as intended, back to UIKit". Seems this is only useful if the cells are white without padding or spacing.